# Keeping text on TextEditor element while switching views SwiftUI

Tags: swift, events, swiftui

Well, I'm working on a little app where I have a TextEditor element to type whatever we want. The case is, I want to keep the text on the TextEditor while switching other views, but I can't.

**TextEditor before switching the view :**
[image: TextEditor before switching the view]

**TextEditor after switching the view :**
[image: TextEditor after switching the view]

The code is the next one:

```
    struct VistaDatos: View {
    
    @State private var opinion: String = ""

    
    var progreso : Double {
        Double(opinion.count)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
         
        VStack{ 
        //SOME CODE HERE ...
            HStack{
                Text("Mi opinión...")
                    .font(.headline)
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            
            VStack{
                TextEditor(text: $opinion)
                    .background(.green)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
                    .background().colorMultiply(.green)
                    .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth:2))
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .onChange(of: self.opinion) { value in
                        if Int(opinion.count) > 150 {
                            self.opinion = String(value.prefix(150))
                        }
                    }
                
                Text("Número de palabras: \(Int(progreso))/150").foregroundColor(Int(progreso) >= 100 ? .red : .white)
                ProgressView(,value: progreso, total: 150) {
                }.frame(width: 350, alignment: .center)
            }
        }.background(Color.green)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

I have to use .onDisappear event to make it work (it seems to be on the first level stack ), but it isn't working...
How can I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This needs a [mre]. Without one, it's very hard to effective debug this and provide an answer.

Comment: I don't know honestly what to provide, I deleted the code that doesn't interfere with the element to make the code more clear

Comment: Well, your question talks about multiple views. And in your code, you show one. Try opening up a new project, and including just what is necessary to make a [mre]

Comment: You need storage of some kind

Comment: try using `AppStorage`, see this link for info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage  Also this link: https://medium.com/swlh/introducing-appstorage-in-swiftui-470a56f5ba9e  There are also other ways to store your data, and then fetch it again when required. Search SO and the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you have multiple views, that I assume may need the `opinion` text,
try this example code. It keeps your text in a `ObservableObject`,
that you can use throughout your app.

For you to do, is to code the save and retrieve
from wherever you want. In this example it is using the `UserDefaults`.

```
class StoreService: ObservableObject {
    // your text
    @Published var opinion = ""
    
    // ... todo code to store your data when you are finished
    func save() {
        // save your data
        UserDefaults.standard.set(opinion, forKey: "opinion")
    }
    
    // ... todo code to retrieve your data when the app starts again
    init() {
        // get your data
        opinion = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "opinion") ?? ""
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var store = StoreService() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack (spacing: 50) {
                Text("\(store.opinion.count) characters typed")
                NavigationLink("go to VistaDatos", value: "editor")
                    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { str in
                        VistaDatos()
                    }
            }
        }.environmentObject(store) // <-- here
    }
}

struct VistaDatos: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: StoreService  // <-- here

    var progreso : Double {
        Double(store.opinion.count)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            //SOME CODE HERE ...
            HStack{
                Text("Mi opinión...").font(.headline)
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            
            VStack{
                TextEditor(text: $store.opinion)  // <-- here
                    .background(.green)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
                    .background().colorMultiply(.green)
                    .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth:2))
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .onChange(of: store.opinion) { value in
                        if store.opinion.count > 150 {
                            store.opinion = String(value.prefix(150))
                        }
                    }
                
                Text("Número de palabras: \(Int(progreso))/150").foregroundColor(Int(progreso) >= 100 ? .red : .white)
                
                ProgressView(value: progreso, total: 150).frame(width: 350, alignment: .center)
                
                Button("Save me") {  // <-- here
                    store.save()
                }
            }
        }.background(Color.green)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the simple `@AppStorage`, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("opinion") var opinion = ""  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack (spacing: 50) {
                Text("\(opinion.count) characters typed")
                NavigationLink("go to VistaDatos", value: "editor")
                    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { str in
                        VistaDatos()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VistaDatos: View {
    @AppStorage("opinion") var opinion = ""  // <-- here

    var progreso : Double {
        Double(opinion.count)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            //SOME CODE HERE ...
            HStack{
                Text("Mi opinión...").font(.headline)
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
            
            VStack{
                TextEditor(text: $opinion) // <-- here
                    .background(.green)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
                    .background().colorMultiply(.green)
                    .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth:2))
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .onChange(of: opinion) { value in
                        if opinion.count > 150 {
                            opinion = String(value.prefix(150))
                        }
                    }
                
                Text("Número de palabras: \(Int(progreso))/150").foregroundColor(Int(progreso) >= 100 ? .red : .white)
                
                ProgressView(value: progreso, total: 150).frame(width: 350, alignment: .center)
            }
        }.background(Color.green)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a monster, thank you so much :). I used .onAppear() and .onDisappear to complement the functionality, and it works fine. Ty again haha